# How to call custom function from tabBarOnPress in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to fire a custom function when a tab is pressed to store which `routeName` tab into Redux.

Normally you'd reference the function with either `this.myFunc` or `this.props.myFunc`. But, I cannot seem to figure out how to access the function via `tabBarOnPress` in `createBottomTabNavigator`. Is this even possible?

Does anyone have any ideas?

```js
const AppStack =  createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Requests: {screen: RequestsStack}
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {

      const { state } = navigation;

      if(state.routes){
        if(state.routes[0].routeName === 'home'){

          // need to call custom function here

        } else if(state.routes[0].routeName === 'requests'){

          // need to call custom function here

        }
      }

      defaultHandler();
    }
  })
})




const Root = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: AppStack,
});
```

Comment: what do you mean? what is `custom function`? React is based on JS, you can always use standard JS for these cases, like create a module, export only your "custom functions" and import them here, calling them when you want to

Comment: @quirimmo your comment helped in the fact that I forgot to just call the function without reference to 'this'. I meant 'custom function' as in not a predetermined function like defaultHander()

Answer (score 0):

With so much reference to 'this' in a component, I brain farted with the fact that I could call a function without reference to 'this'.

I was able to get this working below:

```
const AppStack =  createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Requests: {screen: RequestsStack}
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {

      const { state } = navigation;

      if(state.routes){
        if(state.routes[0].routeName === 'home'){

          store.dispatch(myFunction('home')) 

        } else if(state.routes[0].routeName === 'requests'){

          store.dispatch(myFunction('requests'))

        }
      }

      defaultHandler();
    }
  })
})
```